# breeze: add item to array of complex-type

Tags: javascript, arrays, breeze, durandal

I have a breeze class in durandal-project.
the class (called "employee") includes property of complex-type (named "mainData").
"main-data" include array of complex-type named "childrenList". the complex-type of the elements of the array named "childDTO".
I accept the data from server (c#) and in the client-side (javascript) I want to add and remove items to the array.
after that, I want to send the array with the changes to the server, for saving.

**my question is: how can I add items to array of breeze?**

here is my classes definitions:

**employee:**

```
         addEmployeeType(store);
    function addEmployeeType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "EmployeeDTO",
            namespace: "myServer.Entities",
            autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            dataProperties: {
                Emp_no1: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
                employeeBaseData: {
                    name: "employeeBaseData",
                    complexTypeName: "EmployeeBaseDTO:#myServer.Entities",
                    isNullable: false,
                    isPartOfKey: false
                },

                employeeMainData: {
                    name: "employeePersonalDetails",
                    complexTypeName: "EmployeePersonalDetailsDTO:#myServer.Entities",
                    isNullable: true
                }
        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("EmployeeDTO", null, employeeInit);
    }
```

**MainData:**

```
    addEmployeeMainDataType(store);
    function addEmployeeMainDataType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "EmployeeMainDataDTO",
            namespace: "myServer.Entities",
            isComplexType: true,
            dataProperties: {
                PermGroup: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false },                   
                Expire_Date: { dataType: DataType.DateTime, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false },                  
                ChildrenList: { dataType: DataType.childDTO, isPartOfKey: false, isScalar: false }
            }

        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("EmployeeMainDataDTO", null, null);
    }
```

**child**:

```
      addEmployeeChildType(store);
    function addEmployeeChildType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "ChildDTO",
            namespace: "myServer.Entities",
            isComplexType: true,
            dataProperties: {
                name: { dataType: DataType.String, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false },            

                age: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isPartOfKey: false }
            }

        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("ChildDTO", null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Complex types are different from Navigation Properties in that you can not specify a mapping between the two entities.  A navigation property has a reference from each entity to the other, but you can't do this with complexTypes because they are a property of the parent entity and cannot be assigned to another entity or anything else.

Check the docs for more info - 
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/complextype-properties

Check this answer for more details on how to attach complex types -
[What's the correct way to create an unbound instance of a complex type in breeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544383/whats-the-correct-way-to-create-an-unbound-instance-of-a-complex-type-in-breeze)

Comment: I understood that complex-type are different from Navigation-properties. I know how to create un-bound instace of complext type. but it is not answer for me!

Comment: I need to create array from complex type.  do you want to say that there is not way to do it? think about the follwing simple sample: I have list of gardens (entities). every garden have flower (complex-type), children (complex-type). I have list of adjectives (complex-type, include code and descript). every flower- has array of adjectives. how shold you develop it in breeze?