# breeze array , after push items, know in the server that array has changed

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, breeze, durandal

I have array of breeze in durandal project.
in my client-side, after accept data from server, I push new items to the array.
but when I come to server-side, it not show the array in the "originalValuesMap". it doesn't understanr that if I have add items to array- it mean that the array is now modified.
what should I do?

here is my code:

in model.js, the definition of the classes is:

```
      addPersonType(store);
    function addPersonType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "PersonDTO",
            namespace: "myServer.Entities",
            autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            dataProperties: {
                Emp_no1: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },                   
                personAccessData: {
                    name: "personAccessData",
                    complexTypeName: "PersonAccessDTO:#myServer.Entities",
                    isNullable: true
                }
            }

        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("EmployeeDTO", null, employeeInit);
    }

   addPersonAccessType(store);
    function addPersonAccessType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "PersonAccessDTO",
            namespace: "myServer.Entities",
            isComplexType: true,
            dataProperties: {
                PermGroup: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false },
                PermGroupName: { dataType: DataType.String, isPartOfKey: false },                  

                MultyProfilesList: {  isPartOfKey: false, isScalar: false }
            }

        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("PersonAccessDTO", null, null);
    }
```

my logic is:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.multyProfilesSelectBox.destination().length; i++) {
        vm.data().MultyProfilesList().push(vm.multyProfilesSelectBox.destination()[i]);
    }
```

in the server:

```
      List<EntityInfo> infos;
        string errorMessage = "";
        if (!saveMap.TryGetValue(typeof(PersonDTO), out infos))
        {
            return "";
        }
        foreach (var ei in infos)
        {
            var personData = (PersonDTO)ei.Entity;
            if (personData .IsValid())
            {
                if (ei.EntityState == EntityState.Added)
                {
                   //some code...
                }
                else if (ei.EntityState == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    if (ei.OriginalValuesMap.ContainsKey("personAccessData"))
                    {
                          //some code...
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("there validations errors in employee " + employeeData.GetErrorMessages());
            }
        }
```

the problem is that the condition :

```
        if (ei.OriginalValuesMap.ContainsKey("personAccessData"))
```

return false!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first,**  you have to define your array in another way:

```
       MultyProfilesList: {  
         name: 'multyProfilesList'
         complexTypeName: 'PersonAccessDTO:#myServer.Entities'
         isPartOfKey: false,
         isScalar: false
       }
```

**second**, when you push item to the array, you have create the item as un-bound instance of your complex-type. (see [What's the correct way to create an unbound instance of a complex type in breeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544383/whats-the-correct-way-to-create-an-unbound-instance-of-a-complex-type-in-breeze))

now, try to see if it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how data flows in your application. You ask server for data to show in your browser. Server sends you data. You have data shown. That data is just copy of data from server. Once you modify that copy, it is modified in your browser, but server has no way of knowing that. In order for server to modify real data, you need to send it what has changed. You should make call like this:

```
manager.saveChanges();
```

That should make client send server data which should be saved.

edit: looking at your code, I suggest you check out HotTowel template and tutorial by John Papa. It might make your life easier.

Comment: I know it, I did it. I know how breeze works. But, In the ei.OriginalValuesMap he show me all of the changed object, apart from the changing in the array.

Comment: Are you foreign keys set properly? Is your metadata set properly?

Comment: why do I need foreign key?
can't I simply define array, without detail what its elements contain?
if not: what should I do for adding correctly array-proprty to breeze model, that contains objects, which each object has to filelds: number, and descript. I want that when I add items to property, the class state will be "modified".